# google drive login api without browser

Tags: java, authentication, google-drive-api

I am working with Google Drive and wanna make a permanent login session.

I just found that the google api will ask me to use a browser to obtain an access token.

Is it possible that I could hard-code my username and password or in other ways so that I could program to login to google using code only?

I am using Java.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know it too

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'service' to bypass the browser-based authorization.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation